# Protractor afterEach extract browser.manage().logs() to a helper function

Tags: angular, protractor, jasmine2.0

My overall goal is to extract the browser.manage().logs() to a helper function.  I'm stepping towards this goal by including the `browser.manage().logs()` functionality inside the `afterEach` call inside the test.

I know that my test is throwing a console error.

The inline version of `browser.manage().logs()` will print the error.  Neither the `afterEach` nor the `checkConsole` will print the logs.

What do I need to do to fix this?
Is the inline `browser.manage().logs()` retrieving the error and wiping the log?  I've tried every combination of having them all commented out and the only one that ever works is the inline version.

I also have `protractor-screenshoter-plugin` configured and the report it produces shows the console error under the `Show browsers logs` button.  Is this somehow grabbing the errors and preventing `browser.manage().logs()` from getting it?

conf.ts

```
import { browser, Config } from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {
    plugins: [{
        package: 'protractor-screenshoter-plugin',
        screenshotPath: './protractor/screenshots',
        screenshotOnExpect: 'failure+success',
        screenshotOnSpec: 'none',
        withLogs: true,
        writeReportFreq: 'asap',
        imageToAscii: 'none',
        clearFoldersBeforeTest: true
    }],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1440x900', '--headless'],
        },
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: [ '-headless' ],
        },
        'loggingPrefs' : {"driver": "ALL", "server": "ALL", "browser": "ALL"}
    },

    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'jasmine2',

    baseUrl: 'https://localhost/',
    rootElement: 'app',

    getPageTimeout: 10000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 52000,
        onComplete: null,
        showColors: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        // returning the promise makes protractor wait for the reporter config before executing tests
        return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(pconfig) {
            // console.log("pconfig", pconfig);
        });
    }
};
```

console_helper.ts

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

export let checkConsole = () => {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then((browserLog: any) => {
        // this also fails to print the error message
        console.log("browserLog", browserLog);
   });
}
```

project.ts

```
import { browser, element, by, ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';
const EC = ExpectedConditions;

import { checkConsole } from "./helpers/console_helper";


afterEach(function() {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
        // this fails to print the error message
        console.log("browserLogs", browserLogs); 
    });
});

it("should click on the button and redirect", () => {
    browser.get('/url-it-needs');
    browser.wait(EC.urlContains('/url-it-needs'), 5000);
    let button = element(by.cssContainingText('button', 'BUTTON TEXT'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(button), 5000);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 5000);
    button.click();
    browser.sleep(500);  // wait for the error to be returned from the backend
    /* 
    // this will print the proper error message
   browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
          console.log("browserlogs Inline", browserLogs);
     });  */

   // this times out
   browser.wait(browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url: string) => {
       console.log("URL after click", url);
       expect(url).toMatch("/properUrl");
   }, 5000);
  });
```

Comment: The ES6 syntax seemed to be the problem, so changing the syntax to the answer syntax works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a similar mechanism to read the console when a test fails.
Our solution looks something like this:

```
export function printConsole () {
    return browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(browserLog => {
        browserLog.forEach(log => console.error(log.message));
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('Could not get browser log.'));
};
```

It might make sense to modify it slightly to actually return the log as well:

```
export function getConsole () {
    return browser.manage().logs().get('browser')
    .catch(() => console.log('Could not get browser log.'));
};

export function printConsole () {
    return getConsole.then(browserLog => {
        browserLog.forEach(log => console.error(log.message));
    });
};
```

That way you could also use it for assertions, i.e. check `length === 0` to assert that no console errors are present.

Answer (score 0):

Each time after you read `browser.manage().logs()` in your test case. The logs would be empty. So, you get no logs in the `afterEach`.

You can try to remove `browser.manage().logs()` in your test case and only keep it in the `afterEach`.